# I need to figure out how to delimit a string in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

So, I'm at work atm and I had a co-worker create some SQL code for me to extract out text from a larger description field. The problem I'm running into is it doesn't stop extracting where I need it to. I need it to stop after it either sees the word "Specifications:" or when it finds two CRLF back to back. This would allow it to grab out only the "Features" which is what I'm trying for.

Here's an example of the current code:

```
SELECT IN_Desc, Replace(IN_Desc, Left(IN_Desc, InStr(IN_Desc, "- ") - 1), "")
FROM Inventory
WHERE IN_MfgName = "BERK"
```

Here's an example of the text it's looking through:

> Gulp! has 400 times more scent dispersion than ordinary plastic bait.
>   The extreme scent dispersion greatly expands the strike zone allowing
>   you to catch more fish! Even more impressive, the natural formulation
>   of Gulp! out fishes live bait in head to head field tests. Berkley
>   Gulp! truly is the next generation in soft bait!
>
> Features:
>
> - Ideal on jigs or as a trailer
> - Favorite for all SW species when targeting big fish
> - Proven tail action design swims under all conditions
> - Expand your strike zone with 400x more scent dispersion than plastic baits
> - 15 years of Gulp! evolution…the best keeps getting better
>
> Specifications:
>
> - Bait Length: 6"
> - Color: White
> - Quantity: Per 4
> - Packaging: Bag

Desired output:

> - Ideal on jigs or as a trailer
> - Favorite for all SW species when targeting big fish
> - Proven tail action design swims under all conditions
> - Expand your strike zone with 400x more scent dispersion than plastic baits
> - 15 years of Gulp! evolution…the best keeps getting better

Thanks to everyone in advance for any and all help.

Comment: Sounds like a poor schema choice, where this data should have had it's own field. Hopefully this is part of a project to fix that problem.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using here? (Sql Server, Oracle, Postgres, Mysql, something else)?

Comment: Also based on your Example text, what would be the output you are after?

Comment: +Joel Coehoorn I agree. Ideally, it would have been it's own field. But, since the person that created all of this didn't think ahead, it's not. This solution won't be able to work for everything as some entries don't follow a set standard. But, this will help me extract from about 80% of our entries which will reduce the time it takes for this by about a month.

Comment: +JNevill  Edited post to show desired output. Also, not sure what RDBMS is (pretty new to all this) but I know it's running on Access? lol probably no help. Sorry.

Comment: @EvanCase "Access" is a fine answer! I will update the tags so we pull in the right experts. Do you know if this table is a "Link Table" and if so, to which RDBMS it is linked?

Comment: @JNevill I looked through the "linked table manager" and didn't see it linked to anything. Anywhere else I should look to figure that out? (I really need to learn more code so my questions / responses aren't so dumb).

Comment: That's fine. I suspect you don't have a link table, so this is just pure Access. That will help with the answers. Also, your question isn't dumb. This isn't an easy one to solve.

Comment: @JNevill I appreciate you coaxing the needed info out of me since I crashed and burn with that! :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit ugly, but it seems to do the trick. It may need some tweaking to get exactly what you want, but this will get everything between Features and the next double carriagereturn/linefeed:

```
Mid(yourfield,InStr(1,yourfield, "Features:")+Len("Features:  "),InStr(InStr(1,yourfield, "Features:")+Len("Features:  "),yourfield, Chr(13) & Chr(10) & Chr(13)  & Chr(10)))
```

I'm certain that it could be written prettier, but my access is rusty as hell. I feel like a VBA UDF would be a lot cleaner and then you could employ regex to really strip thing this apart.

Comment: Don't think stops the extract at word `Specifications`.

Comment: @June7 No. It stops at the first encounter of two consecutive CRLFs. That `Chr(13)&Chr(10)&Chr(13)&Chr(10)` could conceivably be replaced with `"Specifications"` and it would probably work just as well, or close enough.

Comment: @JNevill Thank you! I will employ this tomorrow when I get back to work and I'll let you know how it worked out!

Comment: @June7 I tried it as well and it did. I suspect it needs some tweaking, but I got the chunk out that OP was after in my test.

Comment: Deleted my previous comment. I copy/pasted the text from question then copy/pasted your expression, changed field name. Does not stop at `Specifications`. I even edited the text to make sure two CrLf present.

Comment: Hmm... Back to the drawing board then.